# Rollback in oracle 10g

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I have a table from which I deleted one row

```
delete from patient where pid=500;
```

now, I rollback the above query and it is completed successfully but upon querying

```
select *from patient;
```

I get:

> "no rows selected"

so, did rollback undid all operations in the session?

but table structure is present and as per  my little knowledge I think delete
just deletes the record which can be retrieved by rollback or is it because I did not commit my insertions?

Comment: so how many rows where actually deleted by the `delete` statement? SQL clients usually show that number (something like "*42 row(s) deleted*")

Comment: was the row with PID=500 there AND COMMITTED? IF you insert, then delete, then rollback - you wind up at your original empty state.

Comment: I thik so because after insertions If I commit it then delete and rollback works fine as I am able to retrieve the records by rollback after deleting them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Delete from will only delete the data, not the table structure.
2. The rollback should have worked for the DELETE from statement, which creates a save point before it deletes.
3. If it still doesn't work, and if flashback for the table is enabled, to get the data back:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE xxTABLENAMExx
      ENABLE ROW MOVEMENT;

   FLASHBACK TABLE xxTABLENAMExx
     TO TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '20' minute);

   ALTER TABLE xxTABLENAMExx
      DISABLE ROW MOVEMENT;
   ```

Input your time period in minutes where you want the table rolled back to.

Answer (score 0):

This will be a results of session  `autocommit on` , if you are using any kind of java tool or any other tool that run with default  setting of `autocommit on` you lost your capability  for rollback (flashback is still an option ) , to have rollback capability  you need to set your session to `autocommit off`

Comment: In sqlplus run , set autocommit off ,and than try